# How to organize Model if there could be different entities for a View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

I am writting website on ASP.NET MVC4 for real estate selling.

I have some entities, like Flat, House and Land. They are based on the base class Object (with base fields, such as: Price, Square etc.).

There would be one View for displaying selling object on my site. But it can be Flat, House or Land. I can't bind several Models to a View, as I know. But if I'll bind Object model to my View, it won't have such fields, like "FlatsCount" for flat, or "HasGarage" for house.

So, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realistically if you don't know at design time *which* derived type (Flat, House, Land, etc.) will be passed to the view, you wouldn't be able to safely use the additional properties of that derived type without type-checking. This would put behaviour into the view, which is a bad idea.

Instead I would be looking at creating several partial views that are strongly typed - _FlatPartial, _HousePartial, etc. Each one would have HTML to be able to render the type it needs. Then your master view can check the type of the object passed in and render the correct partial accordingly. Something like:

```
if (Model is Flat)
    @RenderPartial("_FlatPartial");
```

or similar.

An alternative would be to create a **custom display template** for each derived type, then just call `@DisplayFor(Model)` and let MVC render the correct display for that type. Not sure if it would work though, as the model may think that all the objects are of the base, not derived, type. In that case the `if...else` approach would be more suitable.